# Join 2 tables by date intersecting ways

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to join 2 tables an interesting way for me, please see details below. Table `PROGRAMS`:

```
STATION_INT | PROGRAM_NAME | AIR_DATE | START_TIME | END_TIME | SEQ_NUM
========================================================================
          1      '70S SHOW '  5/6/2015    32405000   32410000         1
          1      '80S SHOW '  5/6/2015    32415000   34300000         1  
........................................................................
```

Also I have a second table `Ratings`

```
STATION_INT | IMP_DATE | IMP_START_TIME | IMP_END_TIME | IMP_STATUS |   HH | F2_5   
==================================================================================
         1     5/6/2015        32400000       34199000           S    1422   8464
         1     5/6/2015        32400000       34199000           F    1677   9000
         1     5/6/2015        34199000       34310000           S    1522   9160
...................................................................................
```

Resulting table (`PROGRAMS` * `RATINGS`) should be like:

```
STATION_INT | PROGRAM_NAME | AIR_DATE | START_TIME | END_TIME | SEQ_NUM | IMP_DATE | IMP_START_TIME | IMP_END_TIME | HH_S | HH_F | F2_5_S | F2_5_F
========================================================================================================================================================
         1       '70S SHOW '  5/6/2015    32405000    32410000        1   5/6/2015         32400000       34199000   1422   1677     8464     9000    
         1       '80S SHOW '  5/6/2015    32415000    34300000        1   5/6/2015         32400000       34310000 (1422+1522)/2  --- (8464+9160)/2  ---
```

I have no clue how to calculate it in SQL... Please advise

Comment: Please elaborate the condition on which rows between the tables should be joined..

Comment: In your `Ratings` table for row 3, why is `IMP_START_TIME > IMP_END_TIME`

Comment: It would be helpful to have a join condition. Which column(s) should be joined by which logic? I haven't seen identical columns. Maybe the only way could be start_time with imp_start_time and end_time with imp_end_time. But they don't match either. Is there a join logic behind it?

Comment: Fixed figures in tables, now everything should be correct. In general always need to compare `if Programs.times in Ratings.TimeRange then AVG(ratings.HH)`

Comment: @SpanishBoy How do you know which ratings belong to which program? Simply based on the times? e.g. program `70s show` is from `32405000` to `32410000`, to the ratings that belong to it happened between those two times? You don't care about overlap, if it exists?

Comment: i wonder how you join the table together without a single key? and the example you gave us is not correct. 80s show end up having seq_num = 1? please give us something more detail.

Comment: `seq_num` is not important.. >You don't care about overlap, if it exists? Yes, I care about it, please see `80 s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` with conditional aggregation like this.

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM PROGRAMS as P
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT 
    AVG(CASE WHEN R.IMP_STATUS = 'F' THEN HH END) as AVG_F_HH,
    AVG(CASE WHEN R.IMP_STATUS = 'F' THEN F2_5 END) as AVG_F_F2_5,
    AVG(CASE WHEN R.IMP_STATUS = 'S' THEN HH END) as AVG_S_HH,
    AVG(CASE WHEN R.IMP_STATUS = 'S' THEN F2_5 END) as AVG_S_F2_5
FROM Ratings as R 
WHERE R.IMP_DATE = P.AIR_DATE AND R.STATION_INT = P.STATION_INT
AND NOT
(R.IMP_START_TIME >= P.END_TIME OR P.START_TIME >= R.IMP_END_TIME)
) as R
```

**Output**

```
STATION_INT PROGRAM_NAME    AIR_DATE    START_TIME  END_TIME    SEQ_NUM AVG_F_HH    AVG_F_F2_5  AVG_S_HH    AVG_S_F2_5
1   70S SHOW    May, 06 2015 00:00:00   32405000    32410000    1   1677    9000    1422    8464
1   80S SHOW    May, 06 2015 00:00:00   32415000    34300000    2   1677    9000    1472    8812
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37753/1)

Comment: Fantastic idea for me!  Need only adjust output, `row #2` should contain `null` for the HH_F / F2_5 columns

Comment: Also for the `row #2` should be different of `row #1` results

Comment: The Program Start and End time `32400000` , `34199000` overlap with `Ratings` `IMP_START_TIME` and `IMP_END_TIME`. That is why there is a value for `F` record for row #2. Can you explain why it should be `null`?

Comment: Latest :), how can I add `IMP_DATE`, `IMP_START_TIME`, `IMP_END_TIME` to Cross Apply correctly?

Comment: use similar conditional aggregate approach with `MAX` / `MIN` like `MAX(CASE WHEN R.IMP_STATUS = 'F' THEN IMP_START_TIME END)`

Answer (score 1):

As I'm still not 100% sure of the question, I'll try my best with this answer.

```
SELECT p.station_int, p.program_name, p.air_date, p.start_Time, p.end_time, p.seq_Num, AVG(r.hh)
FROM programs as p
INNER JOIN ratings as r
    ON r.imp_date = p.imp_date
    AND (r.imp_start_time >= p.start_time
        AND r.imp_start_time <= p.end_time)
    AND (r.imp_end_time <= p.end_time
        AND r.imp_end_time >= p.start_time)
GROUP BY p.station_int, p.program_name, p.air_date, p.start_Time, p.end_time, p.seq_Num
```

Maybe this will do the thing your looking for.